# LOOP to Look up the value in M Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a following data table:

[image]

I need to create a column called FINAL VALUE with certain rules in the power query editor:

- The FINAL VALUE is created based on the COUNTRY
- If VALUE is greater than 100, then the previous value will be taken
- if the previous values (no previous value such as 202001) are all greater than 100, then 100

So the final table should look like:

[image]

I sort COUNTRY and DATE, and then I try to apply loop in M Query. As I am not familiar with the function in M query, I have hard time figuring out. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What if your 2nd row contain value 90?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are better of in DAX. You can create a new column like below:

```
Final Value = 
var curCountry = TableCountry[Country]
var curDate = TableCountry[Date]
var prevDate = CALCULATE(MAX(TableCountry[Date]), FILTER(TableCountry, curDate >= TableCountry[Date] && curCountry = TableCountry[Country] && TableCountry[Value] <=100))
return LOOKUPVALUE(TableCountry[Value], TableCountry[Country], curCountry, TableCountry[Date], prevDate, 100)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to do it in the M query.

Comment: Could you tell me why this needs to be done in m-guery? I see some options but it is not easy. You will need to work with two tables which you need to merge. On table holds only the records under 100. However, I do not know yet how to create the columns to merge on..